# Grid calculation and export to CSV

Tags: loops, csv, maxima

I have two sets `x` `[xmin,xmax]` and `y` `[ymin, ymax]` and I would like to execute a function going stepwise from the min to the max values of `x` and `y`. So I want to apply a function to the Cartesian product of `x` and `y`. I would then like to save each combination as a row to a CSV file. I've been trying for some time with a `do` loop, but got a bit stuck on how to create the list in the end. For instance:

```
for x: 1 thru 2 step 1 do 
for y: 1 thru 2 step 1 do 
print([x,y,find_root (exp(a*x) = y, a, 0, 1)])
```

I'd get the values of `x` and `y` and the function of all combinations, but I struggle to save it and export it to a CSV, because I don't know how to create the list with `[[1,1,function(1,1)],[1,2,function(1,2)],[2,1,function(2,1)],[2,2,function(2,2)]]`, that I could export with `write_data`.

Alternatively, I'd like to use:

```
xlist:makelist(x,x,1,2,1);
ylist:makelist(y,y,1,2,1);
create_list([x,y,x^y],x,xlist,y,ylist);
```

In this case I don't know how to include the function in create list or how to use map.

How do I do the above or is there a better way?

Comment: I just realized that create list actually accepts functions.
    xlist:makelist(x,x,1,2,1);
    ylist:makelist(y,y,1,2,1); 
    create_list([x,y,find_root (exp(a*x) = y, a, 0, 1)],x,xlist,y,ylist);
But say the cartesian product of x and y has a million combinations, this might take some time

Answer (score 2):

About speeding up the construction of the 1 million item list, how about solving the equation just once and then substituting values of x and y? E.g.:

```
solve (exp(a*x) = y, a);
my_solution : rhs (first (%));
create_list ([x, y, ev (my_solution)], x, xlist, y, ylist);
```

Here `ev` evaluates `my_solution` with the current values of the variables it contains (namely `x` and `y`).

About writing a CSV file, try this:

```
write_data (my_list, "my_output_file", 'comma);
```